# How to create modern background with rotating geometric shapes in HTML5

Tags: html

I saw a background that looks great, but was written using Shockwave. Can this be closely reproduced using HTML5 (no plugins)? Ideally, it would work in IE9+, Firefox 5+ and Chrome 9+. The effect I want is under the text "Customize your peace of mind."

http://www.bluedotsafes.com/information.php?info_id=8

A working example using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be great.

This is the snippet of Shockwave code:
http://jsfiddle.net/RWdeA/1/

Comment: Yes it can be done using HTML5, CSS3, JS, and a modern browser (i.e. not IE)

Comment: While it can be done I think it would be cpu hungry.

Answer (score 0):

A bit complicated to show an entire example on here or jsfiddle, but have a look at http://raphaeljs.com/ , http://paperjs.org/ , or http://easeljs.com/ all three libs can render text and animate background elements.